# How to rename a function globally in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I installed Active Admin and this is the same error that I came across
http://www.rqna.net/qna/mrumzr-argumenterror-in-activeadmin-devise-sessionscontroller-create.html

I would like to rename "sign_in" function globally to "sign_in_". How can I do this correctly? I don't want to mess anything else up.

I tried this method:
    module SessionsHelper
      alias :sign_in_ :sign_in
      undef :sign_in
    end

But it gives me this error when I try to start my rails server. Here's the full error message output in command prompt

```
       Called from: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/action
pack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initi
alize'.

Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load': C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/app/he
lpers/sessions_helper.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $en
d (SyntaxError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:135:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `map!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `modules_for_helpers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:92:in `modules_for_helpers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:95:in `helper'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in with'
        from C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/app/controllers/application_controll
er.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/inherited_reso
urces-1.3.1/app/controllers/inherited_resources/base.rb:11:in `<module:Inherited
Resources>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/inherited_reso
urces-1.3.1/app/controllers/inherited_resources/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/base_controller/menu.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/base_controller/menu.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/resource_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/batch_actions.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/event.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/event.rb:25:in `block in dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/event.rb:24:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/event.rb:24:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/application.rb:187:in `load!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/application.rb:213:in `routes'
        from C:in `routes'
        from C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top
 (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
        from C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (require
d)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `reload_routes!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:34:in `reload!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:61:in `block in attach!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__63132682__prepare__586461675
__callbacks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (re
quired)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\sample_app>
```

Then when I include just alias and undef lines without the "end" in my sessionhelper file, I get the following error output when trying to restart the server

```
Exiting
C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:3:in `<module:Sess
ionsHelper>': undefined method `sign_in' for module `SessionsHelper' (NameError)

        from C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:1:in
`<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:135:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `map!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `modules_for_helpers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:92:in `modules_for_helpers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:95:in `helper'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in with'
        from C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/app/controllers/application_controll
er.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/inherited_reso
urces-1.3.1/app/controllers/inherited_resources/base.rb:11:in `<module:Inherited
Resources>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/inherited_reso
urces-1.3.1/app/controllers/inherited_resources/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/base_controller/menu.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/base_controller/menu.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/resource_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/batch_actions.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/event.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/event.rb:25:in `block in dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/event.rb:24:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/event.rb:24:in `dispatch'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/application.rb:187:in `load!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/application.rb:213:in `routes'
        from C:in `routes'
        from C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top
 (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
        from C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (require
d)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `reload_routes!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:34:in `reload!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.
5.1/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:61:in `block in attach!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__81379729__prepare__328171315
__callbacks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3
/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Users/Me/Desktop/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (re
quired)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do things in the same module as it was defined.

```
module SessionsHelper
  alias :sign_in_ :sign_in
  undef :sign_in
end
```

Comment: Be careful about undefining a third party method. I've not used active admin, but it could be used elsewhere.

Comment: @andy You are right. It may cause a problem depending on how it is used.

Comment: This is the error message that I'm getting when I try to start the rails server:  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469 in 'load': C:/sampleapp/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:49: syntax error

Comment: any ideas on how I could fix the above error when restarting the rails server?

Comment: With alias you just supply the bare method name - no symbols. alias_method requires you to pass symbols (comma separated)

Comment: @FrederickCheung Either bare method name or symbol will work.

Comment: @sawa, do you know if the error message that I'm getting is fixable to use Active Admin?

Comment: @syk Your information is not enough. You should provide the error message.